# deploying several Apps on Google's Cloud Platform,

Tags: php, google-app-engine

When you deploy instances on Google App Engine, you can get the external IP address of each instance using the code (appcfg.py -A studious-rhythm-111707 update app.yaml). However, when you reload the PHP page that reveals the external IP address, you would notice that the addresses would change most of the time after each reload. Perhaps i need answers for below questions.

1) Possible causes that require the change of IP addresses, and explain how changing IP addresses is useful.

2) Propose an alternative to each cause, and explain how it would be better than changing IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior.  Appengine spins up front end instances as required to support a particular load and will load balance between these. In addition you never talk to the instances directly.  The IP addresses you see are in fact mediated by whatever infrastructure google has sitting in front of appengine.

Server IP address should be irrelevant to you if you want to use appengine.

Comment: Yes, you are not actually seeing the IP address of each instance. There is no 1:1 mapping of IP addresses to instances, what you are seeing is a random IP from Google's front-end. It's also impossible to connect to an App Engine instance directly by IP address.